What is the shape of the hidden/cell state of convLSTM2D?
I am new to convLSTM2D and I understood how it works. I have a confusion regarding the shape of the hidden state at different epochs (h_t). Coniser the following code:
input_shape=(11, 70,70,5)
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(Input(shape=input_shape))
model.add(ConvLSTM2D(7, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='valid', return_sequences=True, data_format='channels_last'))
model.summary()

The output shape is as expected (None, 11,70,70,7) which tell me that the shape of h_t (or the cell state c_t) should be (70,70,7) at any epoch.
My question is:  the convolution between h_t and the recurrent kernel (of shape (3,3,7)) must internally use padding='same', although I specified padding='valid' explicitly in the model. Is it the case? Otherwise, if padding='valid' is used in the convolution between h_t and its corresponding kernel at any gate, the shape of h_t will gradually reduce with every epoch. Can you please confirm this?
The following sentence from this blog seems to confirm my thinking.

Note the convolution in h_{t-1} o recurrent_kernel is hardcoded to use 1x1 stride and padding = 'SAME' (TensorFlow code for recurrent_conv), therefore the output shape of convolution does not change.

However, it would be assuring to get a confirmation from here.
